# How to render json data in Python Django App

Tags: python, django

I am new to Python . I am trying to create a webapp from Django which will read data from Excel file and then it will show that data on webpage in a form of dropdown .

This is the structure of my web app which is I am creating
[image: App Structure]

I have also created a python script which is parsing the excel data and returning the json data

```
import pandas
import json

# Read excel document
excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('Test-Data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Convert excel to string
# (define orientation of document in this case from up to down)
thisisjson = excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records')

# Print out the result
print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', thisisjson)
thisisjson_dict = json.loads(thisisjson)

with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(thisisjson_dict, json_file)
```

This is output of this script

```
[{"Name":"Jan","Month":1},{"Name":"Feb","Month":2},{"Name":"March","Month":3},{"Name":"April","Month":4},{"Name":"May","Month":5},{"Name":"June","Month":6},{"Name":"July","Month":7},{"Name":"August","Month":8},{"Name":"Sep","Month":9},{"Name":"October","Month":10},{"Name":"November","Month":11},{"Name":"December","Month":12}]
```

This is what I am to have on html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The select element</h1>

<p>The select element is used to create a drop-down list.</p>

<form action="">
  <label for="months">Choose a Month:</label>
  <select name="months" id="month">
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now where I am stuck is how we can integrate this in my webapp and how we can use this Json data to create a dropdown list on my webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following 3 steps.

1. Write a view function to see your Excel data in your HTML.
2. Add your view function in your urls.py file.
3. Create a loop in your HTML to see your months_data.

**1. my_website/views.py**

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render

def get_months(request):
    months_data = your_json
    return render(request, 'your_html_path', {'months': months_data})
```

**2. my_website/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.get_months),
]
```

**3. home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The select element</h1>

<p>The select element is used to create a drop-down list.</p>

<form action="">
  <label for="months">Choose a Month:</label>
  <select name="months" id="month">

    {% for month in months %}
        <option value={{ month.Month }}>{{ month.Name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you can look for more information about views [Writing views | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/)

and you can look for more information about urls [URL dispatcher | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/)

I hope it works for you!

Comment: I did this change but on the dropdown I am not getting option .I added a log statement 
months_data = get_months()
    print('Excel Sheet to JSON:\n', months_data)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'months': months_data})

Comment: 1. Make sure your html path is true.
2. Make sure your months_data is true.

Answer (score 0):

Why dump to json?
Use pyexcel its easy to understand the docs.
[link docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyexcel/)

Another option is to use ajax, you can implement the excel output (json Response) in a simple way in your template. If you dont want to use pyexcel (which is in most cases sufficient) let me know, then we can get into an ajax example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're using function or class based view, but pass your data in the context

```py
...
context['months'] = [{"Name":"Jan","Month":1}, ...]
...
```

Then in the template iterate over it

```html
...
{% for item in months %}
  <select name="months" id="month">
    <option value="{{ item.Month }}">{{ item.Name }}</option>
  </select>
{% endfor %}
...
```

Comment: That's where I am confused how I can function based or class based view. How I can integrate this script in my webapp